# Missing Authorization Header when using fetch API

Tags: postman, fetch-api, authorization-header

#### Description:

I'm facing a peculiar issue with making a **POST** request to the **`/api/projects`** endpoint in my React application. The request includes the **`Authorization`** header with a valid bearer token (**`accessToken`**). However, when I execute the request using the **`fetch`** API in my React code, it returns:

```
{
  "msg": "Missing Authorization Header"
}
```

Strangely, the same request works very well in Postman, and it also worked for a similar project that I created in the past.

#### Code Snippet:

```
fetch("/api/projects", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(formData),
})
```

Any insights or suggestions on why the same request works in Postman but fails in my React app would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

#### Troubleshooting Steps:

1. Verified that the **`accessToken`** is not **`null`** or **`undefined`**.
2. Temporarily hardcoded the **`Authorization`** header to rule out issues with the **`accessToken`**.
3. Inspected the Network tab in the browser's developer tools to ensure the **`Authorization`** header is present.
4. Checked CORS headers and ensured they are correctly configured on the server side.
5. Explored the browser console for any additional error messages.

Comment: Are you getting a CORS error in your browser's Console tab?

Comment: No. But I checked the network tab. When I send the request, I got 2 responses, the first one with status code 308 and response header: HTTP/1.1 308 PERMANENT REDIRECT.  The next one has response header: HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED

Comment: I got 2 responses, the first one with response headers: HTTP/1.1 308 PERMANENT REDIRECT. The second one with response headers: HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/944

Comment: Still not knowing why the response is redirected with 308 status code.

Comment: how to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @IssaKass Without more information from you, we cannot tell what is causing that redirect... See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Solved! I removed the url_prefix here: app.register_blueprint(projects_bp, url_prefix="/projects"). And hardcoded it in the route: @projects_bp.route("/projects", methods=["POST"]). But why that was the problem, I couldn't understand.